# mainloop is re-executed 4 times after button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

I´m new to TkInter. I Have this program that after a button is clicked it calls a function (processTask) from another module (anotherModule) that takes several minutes to run.

The problem is that after the button is clicked, after a couple of seconds it pops up 4 of the main program windows. I really don't understand why this is happening.

Is there maybe something in my code that is making the program to behave like that?

Thanks in advance

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from anotherModule import *
import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import threading

app = Tk()
app.title("Title")
app.geometry('450x300+200+200')

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("logo.png"))
panel = Label(app, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

message = ''


def handle_click():
    Instruction.config(text='Rquest is being processed')
    pb.start()
    def callback():
        processTask()
        pb.stop()
        pb.config(value=100)
        Instruction.config(text='Fin')


    t = threading.Thread(target=callback)
    t.start()

B = Button(app, command = handle_click)
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("GenHor.PNG"))
B.config(image = img2)
B.pack()
Instruction = Label(app, text=message, font='size, 14')
Instruction.pack()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(app,orient='horizontal',length=300,mode='determinate')

pb.pack()

app.mainloop()
```

**Edit**

I know that is not the best solution but, is there a way to count the executions and do something like this:

```
if counter == 1:
    app.mainloop()
```

So, only if is the first execution would run the mainloop?

Comment: Not sure if that's what's causing your problem, but tkinter isn't thread safe. Avoid modifying the GUI from within a thread.

Comment: Most likely your other modules are creating widgets. The code as posted can't possibly create more than one window.

Comment: That's funny part. It is not. The other module just processes data